# How to read driverpath using relative path mentioned in config.properties file

Tags: java, eclipse

I have config.properties file in `src/main/resources` folder having a property as `"driverFilePath=C:\\VSP\\workspace\\Drivers\\IEDriverServer_Win32_3.5.0\\IEDriverServer.exe"`.

Here I'm currently reading it by mentioning full path, now I want to read only through relative path as `"Drivers\\IEDriverServer_Win32_3.5.0\\IEDriverServer.exe"` instead, as the drivers are also located in svn repo.

I'm using the code as 
`File file = new File(driverFilePath);` to get the path from local.Please suggest a way so that I can mention only relative path like `"Drivers/IEDriverServer_Win32_3.5.0/IEDriverServer.exe"` which will match both my local and also the svn location.Hence I won't be making any change in my code.